# How to correct for perspective when plotting a 3D triangle with texture?

Tags: c#, 3d, gdi

I have been working on a 3D rendering project as a technical excersise to see if I can replicate what a lot of the 3D frameworks do already: all the way from loading the model to plotting the triangles to a buffer ready to be drawn.

Here is a sample of what I have managed to produce
[image: Render of program output]

As you can see from the screenshot I have hit a snag plotting the textures on the surface. This [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping) I have found explains about affine vs non-affine.
Some other links similar to this one about [perspective correct texture mapping](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~mikaelk/doc/perspectivetexture/) go into it in more detail.

I still do not understand how I can correct my UV coordinates when plotting a pixel.

**How my engine currently works with a triangle:**
Convert 3D vertex data into 2D screen data
call draw triangle passing depth between 0 & 1 and texture details
within draw triangle each vertical line is draw by interpolating along the 3 edges of the triangle

I have made the changes in the links but I get divide by zero errors. If I ignore them nothing is drawn.

**The question**

How can I correct the UV co-ordinate selected at each pixel. Currently at each pixel I know the depth between 0.0 and 1.0, the apparent UV.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Tom :)

**UPDATE:**

Solution, use Andreas Brinck's answer. It works fine. Below is a screenshot of it now working.

[image: working correct perspective texture mapping]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of interpolating u and v over the triangle, interpolate u/z, v/z and 1/z (calculated at the vertices) and retrieve the perspective correct coordinates as (u/z) / (1/z) and (v/z) / (1/z).

Comment: I will have a go at that modification and see how that goes. I seem to remember trying something similar to this following another resource and to no prevail.

Comment: I don't know if I just needed re-explaining it but that works. I will post a working screenshot now. Thank you :)

Comment: Cool, glad to be able to help!